# Alarms are getting cancelled after closing app from the task manager

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm

Alarms are active when the app is in foreground and as well as in the background. But when removed from the recent apps or closing from the task manager, alarms are getting cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

With Android O there are few changes in background execution, so google guys are suggesting using JobScheduler Api for scheduling tasks which will run even when the application is in background or closed by user.

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html)